# Showing two segments are congruent

Tags: geometry, circles

ABCD is a square. Draw the quarter circle centred at D with radius DA. Draw the semicircle of diameter AD. With point P on arc AC, $PQ \perp AB$, and $PD \cap \text{arc} AD = R$. Show that $PQ=PR$. [image: My own illustration of the problem here]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNc2g.png)

Comment: Can you show some of your own effort or approach? Where do you get stuck with the problem? Math Stackexchange wants to help you solve it, not solve it for you.

Comment: I have been looking at this problem for a while and I have absolutely no idea where to even start. Problems we have done are not similar to this one. @Jonathan

Comment: $PD \cap \text{arc} AD = R$ What does this line mean? Thanks.

Comment: i edited the picture

Comment: @rover2 Hint: $\,\triangle RDA\,$ is a right triangle.

Comment: HINT: You can show that triangles $APR$ and $APQ$ are congruent.

Comment: Is Q the middle of AB? It seems that the problem not well defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join $AR$ and $AP$. Let $E$ be the intersection between $AP$ and arc $AR$ such that $E\ne A$. Let $F$ denote the midpoint of $AD$.

Since $AB$ is tangent to $\odot D$ at $A$, we know that $\angle PAQ=\frac 12\angle ADP$. Also, $AB$ is tangent to $\odot F$ at $A$, we know that $\angle PAQ=\angle ADE$. Therefore, $\angle ADE=\angle EDR$. Since $\angle RAP=\angle EDR$, we conclude that $\angle RAP=\angle PAQ$. Since it is obvious that $\angle ARP=\angle AQP=90^\circ$ and $AP=AP$, $\triangle RAP$ is congruent to $\triangle QAP$, which yields that $RP=PQ$.

[image]

Comment: i am having trouble seeing how you made the construction. could you by chance include a picture?

Comment: @rover2 Please see above.

Comment: is E constructed to be the midpoint of arc$AR$? is that why $\angle PAQ = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2} \angle ADP$?

Comment: @rover2 It is not constructed to be the midpoint of arc $AR$. Instead, we can show that it is. Actually, since both $P$ and $A$ are on $\odot D$, $DP=DA$ (all equal to the radius of $\odot D$), while $DE\perp AP$, we know that $\angle AED=\angle EDP$.